# webRTC - Ring sound on remote peer browser

Tags: javascript, webrtc

I am new to webRTC thing. I have been trying to make remote peer's browser play sound when there is an incoming webRTC call offer.

I tried to use HTML hidden `<Audio>` and then on offer use play function. But browsers have auto-play policy and needs user interaction. So this is not feasible.
Then I read about webAudio API but again the same issue, needs user interaction as mentioned [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API/Best_practices#Autoplay_policy).

I think I spent enough time on this and couldn't find any way. Now I am thinking if this is somehow possible through RTCDatachannels. Can I send audio to the remote peer and play it there directly because as far as I know they don't need permission unlike mic/cam for the calls?

Any advice on how to go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this function and in the interval put the duration of your sound:

```
function playSound() {
   let src = '/media/notification.ogg';
   let audio = new Audio(src);
   audio.play();
   setInterval(function(){audio.pause();  }, 1500);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. As I mentioned, browsers do not allow auto-play without user interaction. They block the audio.

Comment: @Newbie but I am already using this function to play a sound once any connection added.
I am putting this function on peer added and it works fine on chrome and firefox.